# PHP not deleting and inserting data right

Tags: php, jquery

How this code works is every time a user visits the page, i scrape all of the data from the table and pass it through the below posts. If the user hasn't accessed that page before and the database is empty with their cookie_id, then it inserts the content, if it is found then it deletes the content from the database and inserts it again. The problem I am having though is that when the deletion occurs it deletes everything and seems to insert one value from $data1 instead of all the data from $data. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Backend:

```
    $cookie_id = $this->input->cookie("session_id");
    $selected_size = $this->input->post('selected_size');
    $product_id = $this->input->post('product_id');
    $product_name = $this->input->post('product_name');
    $product_color = $this->input->post('product_color');

    $q1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM default_cart_temp
                            WHERE cookie_id = '$cookie_id'
                            AND is_paid = 'No'");
    if ($q1->num_rows() > 0) {
        $this->db->where('cookie_id', $cookie_id);
        $this->db->delete('default_cart_temp');

        foreach($product_id as $key => $value) {
            $data1 = array('selected_size' => $selected_size[$key],
                          'product_id' => $value,
                          'product_name' => $product_name[$key],
                          'product_color' => $product_color[$key],
                          'cookie_id' => $cookie_id,
                          'is_paid' => 'No');
        } $this->db->insert('default_cart_temp', $data1);
        echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
    } else {
        foreach($product_id as $key => $value) {
            $data = array('selected_size' => $selected_size[$key],
                          'product_id' => $value,
                          'product_name' => $product_name[$key],
                          'product_color' => $product_color[$key],
                          'cookie_id' => $cookie_id,
                          'is_paid' => 'No');
        } $this->db->insert('default_cart_temp', $data);
    }
```

Frontend:

```
   selected_size = $('.selected_size1').text();
    arr1 = selected_size.split(".");
    ss1 = arr1.slice(0, -1);

    product_id = $('.product_id1').text();
    arr2 = product_id.split(".");
    ss2 = arr2.slice(0, -1);

    product_name = $('.product_name1').text();
    arr3 = product_name.split(".");
    ss3 = arr3.slice(0, -1);

    product_color = $('.product_color1').text();
    arr4 = product_color.split(".");
    ss4 = arr4.slice(0, -1);

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        url: "<?=base_url()?>index.php/products/products/new_instance",
        data: { selected_size: ss1, product_id: ss2, product_name: ss3, product_color: ss4 },
        json: {success: true},
        success: function(data) {
          if(data.success == true) {
            alert("True");
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: Can `insert()` accept multiple rows at once? If not, I think the `insert()` call should be within the foreach not outside?

Comment: And don't you need to specify what to delete from 'default_cart_temp'? To me it looks like you are telling it to delete all entries in that table with this instruction: `$this->db->delete('default_cart_temp');`;

Answer (score 1):

In every `foreach` loop execution you are overriding `$data` and `$data1` variables. You have to change them to arrays and add data like this `$data[] = $subArray`.